# Ext Js uploading file brings up one file dialog on response

Tags: javascript, asp.net, file-upload, extjs

I have the following code which I am submitting to an aspx page

```
 fp.getForm().submit({
                         url: 'SomeAspxPage',
                         method: 'POST',
                         waitMsg: 'Uploading your file...',
                         isUpload: true, 
                            success: function(fp, o){
                               alert('success');                                
                         },
                         failure: function(form, action) {
                                alert('failed)';
                            },
                            form: fp.getForm().getEl().dom
                        });
```

The files get submitted and I can save it ot do whatever.  My problem is that even though I set the response content-type to be application/json the browser always opens the 'open file' dialog which contains the json string I am returning.  Does anyonw know why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

You should set `content-type` as `text/html`.

Comment: Clearly thats exactly what you shouldnt do.